# How to create a VM using VSphere java API?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I want to write some java code to create a VM, install iso (or copy the existing vm set up if install iso is not possible) and assign disk space, create login for the created VM.

I looked at Vsphere API examples in http://vijava.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vijava/trunk/src/com/vmware/vim25/mo/samples/, it has power on/off of installed VM. I could not figure out how to create one with the API. I have two questions:

1. What are the steps to create VM using API?
2. What API or objects should be used to create VM programatically?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

I know i am about a year late, but when you download the SDK, you will have a sample how to create a VMdisk. Understand the code and then you can just do it your way :)

The link to the SDK.zip file 
http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/developer/forums/java_toolkit

and inside the SDk, the VMDisk file:
\SDK\vsphere-ws\java\JAXWS\samples\com\vmware\vm

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to keep the [VMware Web Services SDK documentation](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/right-pane.html) handy - unfortunately they changed formats recently so I'm not sure how good of deep links I can get for you. The specific method I've used is [CreateVM_Task](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.Folder.html#createVm) (you'll have to scroll down to find it on the Folder object). Alternatively, if you're using a resource pool, [CreateChildVM_Task](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.ResourcePool.html&path=5_0_2_5_3_37) may be more applicable (again, scroll down to find it).

There is also a section of [documentation on creating VMs](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50/PG_Ch10_VM_Config.12.3.html) that has some incomplete example code.

As far as where in the hierarchy to create the VM, that's up to you. Each host or cluster will have a vmfolder property that you can use to create VMs, or any other folder may work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Evan. I am able to create the VM. A further question, how could I add os to the VM? Should I get an OVF file first then apply to VM?

Comment: If you've got an OVF file, you can just import it as-is. See this method: http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/topic/com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc_50/vim.ResourcePool.html#importVApp